# How can I place five tables on a page, in a 3x2 matrix?

Tags: tables

I'd like to insert multiple code-generated tables into a document so that they appear on a single page.  I may need to use smaller font to make them all fit.  All the tables are of the same size, and are already in their own `tabular` block with captions and labels.  What's the best strategy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the tables into minipages or parboxes or use the `subfig` package.  Just remember that you can't put multiple `table` environments together, but you *can* put multiple `tabular` environments (with captions and labels) within a single `table` environment. The `subfig` documentation has information about both techniques.

Here's an example using both `parboxes` and `minipages`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\parbox{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
0.096356125 & 0.126535287 & 0.222951743 \\
0.011227006 & 0.154678302 & 0.134139901 \\
0.695793117 & 0.287078523 & 0.077578477 \\
0.325214308 & 0.069604001 & 0.657673026 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{ABC}
}\bigskip
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
D & E & F \\
\midrule
0.692628962 & 0.676885786 & 0.714726267 \\
0.216724956 & 0.514742162 & 0.274775702 \\
0.520019549 & 0.506134903 & 0.293514122 \\
0.186925802 & 0.285319488 & 0.403563324 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{DEF}
}\bigskip

\parbox{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
G & H & I \\
\midrule
0.037156909 & 0.76115364 & 0.238202162 \\
0.086680665 & 0.028714787 & 0.879055353 \\
0.302193464 & 0.157574379 & 0.948781632 \\
0.503584342 & 0.885553012 & 0.30105766 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{GHI}
}\bigskip
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
J & K & L \\
\midrule
0.652587435 & 0.812241976 & 0.816788302 \\
0.456616676 & 0.320706153 & 0.882116653 \\
0.616582591 & 0.361915305 & 0.772590298 \\
0.78771219 & 0.53200612 & 0.564641396 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{JKL}
}
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
M & N & O \\
\midrule
0.733808918 & 0.699601932 & 0.11500169 \\
0.873043748 & 0.12076117 & 0.682781587 \\
0.918180185 & 0.63535945 & 0.445837393 \\
0.417373347 & 0.731406679 & 0.669593201 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{MNO}
}
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{\ }
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
0.096356125 & 0.126535287 & 0.222951743 \\
0.011227006 & 0.154678302 & 0.134139901 \\
0.695793117 & 0.287078523 & 0.077578477 \\
0.325214308 & 0.069604001 & 0.657673026 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{ABC}
}\end{minipage}\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
D & E & F \\
\midrule
0.692628962 & 0.676885786 & 0.714726267 \\
0.216724956 & 0.514742162 & 0.274775702 \\
0.520019549 & 0.506134903 & 0.293514122 \\
0.186925802 & 0.285319488 & 0.403563324 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{DEF}
}\end{minipage}\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
G & H & I \\
\midrule
0.037156909 & 0.76115364 & 0.238202162 \\
0.086680665 & 0.028714787 & 0.879055353 \\
0.302193464 & 0.157574379 & 0.948781632 \\
0.503584342 & 0.885553012 & 0.30105766 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{GHI}
}\end{minipage}\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
J & K & L \\
\midrule
0.652587435 & 0.812241976 & 0.816788302 \\
0.456616676 & 0.320706153 & 0.882116653 \\
0.616582591 & 0.361915305 & 0.772590298 \\
0.78771219 & 0.53200612 & 0.564641396 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{JKL}
}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}

\toprule
M & N & O \\
\midrule
0.733808918 & 0.699601932 & 0.11500169 \\
0.873043748 & 0.12076117 & 0.682781587 \\
0.918180185 & 0.63535945 & 0.445837393 \\
0.417373347 & 0.731406679 & 0.669593201 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{MNO}
}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}{\ }\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought of minipage, but only found examples for multi-column use, not matrix...  What would be minipage usage here?

Comment: @Alexy I added an example.  If your tables are small and you can fit 3 in the width of the page, you can adjust the size of the `\parbox` or `minipage` accordingly.

Comment: You mean the `subfig` package.

Answer (score 4):

resize the tabulars that three fit in one row:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx,blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}
\centering
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
A & B & C \\\midrule
0.096356125 & 0.126535287 & 0.222951743 \\
0.011227006 & 0.154678302 & 0.134139901 \\
0.695793117 & 0.287078523 & 0.077578477 \\
0.325214308 & 0.069604001 & 0.657673026 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{ABC}
\endminipage\hfill%
%
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
A & B & C \\\midrule
0.096356125 & 0.126535287 & 0.222951743 \\
0.011227006 & 0.154678302 & 0.134139901 \\
0.695793117 & 0.287078523 & 0.077578477 \\
0.325214308 & 0.069604001 & 0.657673026 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{ABC second}
\endminipage\hfill%
%
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
A & B & C \\\midrule
0.096356125 & 0.126535287 & 0.222951743 \\
0.011227006 & 0.154678302 & 0.134139901 \\
0.695793117 & 0.287078523 & 0.077578477 \\
0.325214308 & 0.069604001 & 0.657673026 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{ABC third}
\endminipage

\bigskip
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
A & B & C \\\midrule
0.096356125 & 0.126535287 & 0.222951743 \\
0.011227006 & 0.154678302 & 0.134139901 \\
0.695793117 & 0.287078523 & 0.077578477 \\
0.325214308 & 0.069604001 & 0.657673026 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{ABC forth}
\endminipage\space%
%
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
A & B & C \\\midrule
0.096356125 & 0.126535287 & 0.222951743 \\
0.011227006 & 0.154678302 & 0.134139901 \\
0.695793117 & 0.287078523 & 0.077578477 \\
0.325214308 & 0.069604001 & 0.657673026 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{ABC fifth}
\endminipage%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worryingly, omitting comment sign % in \hfill% above and the subsequent % on a line by itself emits a single column...  Why so brittle?

Comment: Otherwise you get an additional space and a new paragraph

Comment: How do we resize the caption accordingly?  It won't go into the resizebox...

Comment: it looks ugly (!), when you resize the caption, too! The reader do not want to use magnifiers ... However, put the `\resizebox` around the `minipage`